# Setting lookup value variable in SharePoint 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, 2016, workflow-variable

I am looking to set a variable in a SharePoint 2010 workflow in a SharePoint 2016 Enterprise env. as a lookup value. The issue that I am having is that the variable data is coming from the EditForm.aspx when a new document is created, so the lookup value is finding that column as empty when the workflow runs initially causing a coercion error. Suggestions for a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my own problem. When you are pulling a lookup value, it must attached to the "Title" column of that list. You cannot pull from custom columns.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the workflow run when an item is created?

For your issue, I suggest you add a "IF" condition into your workflow, if the lookup value is empty, do other things, else set the variable value, like: 
[image]

Comment: Hi, Kally. Thank you for the suggestion but I actually resolved my own problem. I will post the answer.